SQLite - how to INSERT nested json data into related tables
In SQLite, I want to insert the following json data into two related tables, form (parent) and waterIntake (child), connected through the foreign key 'currentDate' in waterIntake that references the table form.
With json_each() and and json_extract() I am able to fill the columns amountWater and timeWater in the table waterIntake. But I am unable to get the value 'currentDate' into this table.
This is my data in testData.json:
{
    "form" :  {
        "currentDate" : "01–05-2024",
        "currentWeight" : 80,
        "waterIntake" : {
            "defaultCupSize": 123,
            "totalAmountWater": 669,
            "cupArray": [
                { "amountWater": 122, "timeWater": "01.05.2024" },
                { "amountWater": 223, "timeWater": "01.05.2024" },
                { "amountWater": 324, "timeWater": "01.05.2024" }
            ]
        }
    }
}   

Here are my INSERT statements:
INSERT INTO form2 (
    currentDate,
    currentWeight,
    defaultCupSize,
    totalAmountWater
)
SELECT
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.currentDate'),
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.currentWeight'),
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.waterIntake.defaultCupSize'),
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.waterIntake.totalAmountWater')
FROM json_each(readfile('testData.json'));



INSERT INTO waterIntake2 (
    currentDate, 
    amountWater,
    timeWater
)
SELECT 
    '01-05-2024', // here I need to insert the currentDate for each row
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.amountWater'),
    json_extract(json_each.value, '$.timeWater') 
FROM json_each(readfile('testData.json'), '$.form.waterIntake.cupArray');

Here are my CREATE TABLE statements:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS waterIntake2 (
    currentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
    amountWater INTEGER, 
    timeWater TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(currentDate) REFERENCES form2(currentDate) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS form2 (
    currentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
    currentWeight INTEGER, 
    defaultCupSize INTEGER,
    totalAmountWater INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(currentDate)
    
);


Does turning on https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_defer_foreign_keys make a difference? (Might have to use one transaction for both inserts)

Does including .from solves the problem, i.e.: $.from.currentDateor $.from.waterIntake.defaultCupSize`?
